# GitHub CI with maven testing not running any tests

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, continuous-integration, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm an absolute newbie to CI and GitHub, and especially the combination of the two.
I have a group project where we use maven for building, maven surefire with junit 5 for testing. We have a couple of tests that run just fine locally, but no config of our maven.yml the repo doesn't run these tests. Here's the current iteration of the .yml (all the currently commented lines are ones that we tested):

```
name: Java CI with Maven
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      #run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      run: mvn --batch-mode --update-snapshots verify
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
    #- name: Test with Maven
      #run:  mvn -Dtest="test/*Test" test
      #run: mvn '-Dtest=test.*Test' test
```

and here's our current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Izsakazsivany</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>maven-unit-test</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Using this and the default "test" lifecycle from Intellij's maven integration, all our tests are ran locally. (The intellij maven test lifecycle uses the following line for testing to my knowledge:
`test -f pom.xml`). However when we try this on GitHub using our CI configuration it says that no tests were found in the default test:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) @ Izsakazsivany ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

(side note: izsakazsivany is our project name
side note2: there are about 100 lines of downloads between the 2 above lines)

What is causing this discrepancy between the local version and the one on GitHub, how come it's not seeing the tests when the same mvn commands are ran?

Edit: This may be an important specification our tests are in a package called test and in specific packages for the separate classes that are tested.
Example: `git/src/main/test/entity`

Comment: what happens when you run `mvn test` locally, from a command line, not from intellij?

Comment: @Eugene I haven't tested that as I don't have maven installed outside of Intellij, will try that now

Comment: Just a side note, the preferred way to override a plugin version, as you have for `maven-surefire-plugin` is to use `<pluginManagement>`, not `<plugins>`. You also have conflicting things in your POM. This line `<maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>` and the one below it are specifying JDK 15, and then your compiler plugin is specifying Java 8 `<source>1.8</source>`. You could clean up your POM a bit by removing the compiler plugin completely (it is bound implicitly anyway), and using Java 8 in `maven.compiler.source/target` in your properties.

Comment: @devor110 You don't need to install it separately, you can call the bundled one from the command line. It exists somewhere like `/C/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/mvn`

Comment: @Eugene tested it locally with `mvn test` and it worked fine just like in intellij

Comment: so your tests are not in `src/test/java`? `mvn test` run locally from command line should have not found them. there are ways to instruct surefire on how to add custom paths for tests to be found

Comment: yes the path does not have a /java, after /test are separate packages. but `mvn test` did find all of them. When I tried testing a specific class locally it did correctly only run the tests found in that

Comment: To get unit tests running with JUnit Jupiter you have to use at least version 2.22.2 of surefire plugin. I strongly recommend to use more recent version...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't see how that could have caused the discrepancy between the local version running perfectly and the one in the repo ignoring all the tests, regardless I tried a more recent version, but nothing changed still.

Comment: Please show a single test which does not being executed and furthermore make an example project on github or alike

Comment: @khmarbaise The only example I can give regarding tests not running is in the original question, where we use `mvn test` for example, hundreds of lines are shown as the VM downloads our repository and all the dependencies for testing, then after that ends it writes `"No tests to run"`, locally it writes the line before that, but afterwards it does go through all the tests, when using `mvn test`. In terms of examples project, is it fine if I just link the existing repo? The project is public anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is resolved finally, the issue was with a bad project structure and we needed to add a line to pom.xml detailing where the tests can be found.
`<testSourceDirectory>src/main/test/java/com/team</testSourceDirectory>`

Edit: The issue most likely had to do with bad project structure, as our tests folder was to deep down. By extension this also meant that our package names also had to be redone. Advice: make sure your project structure is correct at the very start to avoid issues like this.